# wpf prism and custom control

Tags: wpf, controls, prism

i need help with creation custom control and prism library.

custom control must have two columns. And using prism library i want 
insert in region some view

what i have:

```
public class MyContentControl : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Content", typeof(object),
            typeof(MyContentControl), null);

    [Bindable(true)]
    public object Content
    {
        get { return GetValue(ContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty Content2Property = DependencyProperty.Register("Content2", typeof(object),
        typeof(MyContentControl), null);

    [Bindable(true)]
    public object Content2
    {
        get { return GetValue(Content2Property); }
        set { SetValue(Content2Property, value); }
    }
}
```

and ResoureDictionary

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyContentControl}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyContentControl}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                  <ColumnDefinition/>
                                  <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinition>
                            <ContentControl Grid.Column="0" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"                                                  
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            Background="IndianRed"/>
                            <ContentControl Grid.Column=1  Content="{TemplateBinding Content2}"
                                             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            Background="Aqua" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

what i want is use it like

```
<MyContentControl>
     <MyContentControl.Content1>
           <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static constants:RegionNames.Content1_Region}"/>
     </MyContentControl.Content1>
     <MyContentControl.Content2>
           <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static constants:RegionNames.Content2_Region}"/>
     </MyContentControl.Content2>
</MyContentControl >
```

Comment: and the question is... what exactly? what does not work? which exception do you get?

Comment: @Haukinger doesn't show new view in region Content1_Region or Content2_Region